# query for two tables and have one column populate based on first match

Tags: sql-server, join, header, match

This is one of those things I am sure has been discussed 1000 times, but all my searches have come just short of me understanding what I need.

Two tables: ledger and patient

I want to select several columns from ledger, and add one column from patient based on two records matching. Here is the query I wrote, but it just runs forever:

```
SELECT 
   ledger.OID
    , ledger.PATID
    , ledger.PROVIDERID
    , ledger.LTYPE
    , ledger.TRANDATE
    , ledger.ESTINS
    , ledger.AMOUNT
    , ledger.PATPAID
    , ledger.PATADJUST
    , ledger.LEDGERID
    , ledger.TYPE2
    , ledger.rpid
    , patient.oid
    , ledger.DESCR
FROM 
    [exportb].[dbo].[LEDGER]
    , exportb.dbo.patient
INNER JOIN 
    LEDGER AS LEDGE ON LEDGE.rpid = PATIENT.rpid
WHERE 
    ledger.PATID > '0'
    AND ledger.LTYPE <> 'M'
    AND ledger.LTYPE <> 'n'
    AND (
        ledger.ESTINS <> '0'
        OR ledger.AMOUNT <> '0'
        OR ledger.PATPAID <> '0'
        OR ledger.PATADJUST <> '0'
        )
```

When I run it without the `patient.oid` and join statement, I get 40037 records, which is exactly what I want.

What I want to do is add the patient.oid header to me results. I want the query to look at the `LEDGER.RPID` column and match the `PATIENT.RPID` column and populate `PATIENT.OID` for that record.

I'm sure it's simple, but was hoping someone could shed some light!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should **most definitely** not **MIX** the two styles!

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no predicate joining `dbo.patient` so are therefore getting a cross join ([Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)):

```
from [exportb].[dbo].[LEDGER],exportb.dbo.patient
```

This should be:

```
FROM    dbo.Ledger
        INNER JOIN dbo.Patient
            ON Patient.rpid = Ledger.rpid
```

You also never reference the table aliased as `LEDGE` anywhere apart from the join, so you may as well remove this completely. So, I think what you are after is:

```
USE Exportb;

SELECT  l.OID,
        l.PATID,
        l.PROVIDERID,
        l.LTYPE,
        l.TRANDATE,
        l.ESTINS,
        l.AMOUNT,
        l.PATPAID,
        l.PATADJUST, 
        l.LEDGERID, 
        l.TYPE2, 
        l.rpid, 
        p.oid, 
        l.DESCR 
FROM    dbo.Ledger AS l
        INNER JOIN dbo.Patient AS p
            ON p.rpid = l.rpid
WHERE   l.PATID > 0
AND     l.LType NOT IN ('M', 'n')
AND     (l.Estins <> 0 OR l.Amount <> 0 OR l.PatAdjust <> 0);
```

Of note, I have removed the cross join, and left a single join to `dbo.Patient`. I have simplified the following predicates:

```
AND ledger.LTYPE <> 'M' 
AND ledger.LTYPE <> 'n'
```

to

```
AND     l.LType NOT IN ('M', 'n')
```

I have also taken what I assume to be numeric constants out of single quotes to avoid implicit conversions, and also removed `ledger.PATPAID <>'0'` from the following line:

```
AND (ledger.ESTINS <> '0' OR ledger.AMOUNT <> '0' or ledger.PATPAID <>'0' or ledger.PATADJUST <> '0')
```

Since the part can never be true because of the predicate:

```
WHERE   l.PATID > 0
```

If you have a one to many relationship from ledger to patients, i.e. you have multiple rows in `dbo.patient` and only care about the first match, then you will need to change your join to an [`APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and use `TOP 1` to get a single row. Your title seems to suggest you want the "first match", but the question does not explain how you define "first":

```
USE Exportb;

SELECT  l.OID,
        l.PATID,
        l.PROVIDERID,
        l.LTYPE,
        l.TRANDATE,
        l.ESTINS,
        l.AMOUNT,
        l.PATPAID,
        l.PATADJUST, 
        l.LEDGERID, 
        l.TYPE2, 
        l.rpid, 
        p.oid, 
        l.DESCR 
FROM    dbo.Ledger AS l
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 p.oid
            FROM    dbo.Patient AS p
            WHERE   p.rpid = l.rpid
            ORDER BY p.oid -- YOU MAY NEED TO CHANGE THIS ORDER DEPENDING ON YOUR CRITERIA
        ) AS p
WHERE   l.PATID > 0
AND     l.LType NOT IN ('M', 'n')
AND     (l.Estins <> 0 OR l.Amount <> 0 OR l.PatAdjust <> 0);
```

Comment: This gets me closer. I think I left out an important detail (I apologize). The ledger table will have multiple RPIDs that are the same. I want to look at each row of the ledger table, compare the RPID it to the patient RPID and populate the patient.OID on the FIRST HIT. I THINK this solution runs through the entire patient table and ledger table - it returned over 133000 records when I only want 40037. if I do a distinct, I get 40054 records, but this is not exactly what I need. Does this make sense>

Comment: This does make sense, but how are you defining **FIRST HIT**? You need to give the columns to order by to ensure that the first hit is consistent.

Comment: This revision does exactly what I need GarethD - thank you. I am a complete newb to legit SQL queries so I will use this code and tear it down and learn from it. I appreciate the assistance and the logic!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `LEFT JOIN` my friend. Change the join from `INNER` to `LEFT` and you will get the results.

The column `Patient.OID` will be `NULL` where there is no match.

And yes, the from clause and join clause is incorrect, which is why it is running forever.

Change it to:

```
from [exportb].[dbo].[LEDGER] LEDGE
LEFT JOIN exportb.dbo.patient ON LEDGE.rpid = PATIENT.rpid
```

Comment: Tried this and it still runs forever - I stopped it at 499,802 records. Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: try: `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [exportb].[dbo].[LEDGER] LEDGE
LEFT JOIN exportb.dbo.patient ON LEDGE.rpid = PATIENT.rpid`, without the where clause. Do you get the record count in resonable time? What is the record count in both these tables? Do you have indexes on the columns used in join?